# Script for gathering information on computers getting stolen

Tags: vbscript

I have put together a small VBScript to gather a bunch of information and email at scheduled intervals, so that one day, should it happen, and my computers are stolen, I may be able to provide relevant and accurate information to the authorities to expedite their return.

I wanted to share what I have done in an effort for it to be finessed (I am not a programmer), but it seems to work well. I also hope it may be of benefit to others.

I currently use the following: Nirsoft utilities for detailed info Mini Relay Server to send the emails ScreenShot Capture to record screen activity both the relay and screen capture programs set to start at login, and VBScript scheduled deep in the hierarchy of Task Scheduler.

Again, I am open to any and all mods/suggestions to this with the hope this becomes valuable for someone that one day needs it.

```
On Error Resume Next
'Option Explicit

Dim dtmStart, lngSeconds, WAN_IP

Dim http
Set http = CreateObject( "MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp" )
http.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
http.Send
WAN_IP = http.responseText   'or do whatever you want with it
Set http = Nothing
'wscript.echo WAN_IP

Set http = CreateObject( "MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp" )
http.Open "GET", "http://viewdns.info/whois/?domain=" & WAN_IP, False
http.Send
WhoIS = http.responseText   'or do whatever you want with it
Set http = Nothing

Set http = CreateObject( "MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp" )
http.Open "GET", "http://viewdns.info/reversedns/?ip=" & WAN_IP, False
http.Send
ReverseDNS = http.responseText   'or do whatever you want with it
Set http = Nothing


Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c ipconfig /all >> c:\temp\ipconfig.txt", 0, true)

Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\whois.html",True)
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\whois.html",2)
objfile.Write Whois
objFile.Close

Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\ReverseDNS.html",True)
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\ReverseDNS.html",2)
objfile.Write ReverseDNS
objFile.Close

return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\BrowsingHistoryView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\browserhistory.html"" /sort ""Visit Time"" /sort ""URL"" /HistorySource 1 /VisitTimeFilterType 3 /VisitTimeFilterValue 1 /LoadIE 1 /LoadFirefox 1 /LoadChrome 1 /LoadSafari 1", 0, true)
WScript.Sleep 5000
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\FBCacheView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\facebookcache.html""", 0, true)
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\WifiInfoView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\wifiinfo.html"" /sort ""~Signal Quality"" /sort ""SSID""", 0, true)
WScript.Sleep 5000
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\WifiHistoryView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\wifihistory.html"" /sort ""~Event Time""", 0, true)
WScript.Sleep 500
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\cprocess.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\cprocess.html""", 0, true)
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\TurnedOnTimesView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\turnon.html"" /sort ~1""", 0, true)
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\WirelessConnectionInfo.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\wireless.html""", 0, true)
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\WirelessKeyView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\wirelesskey.html""", 0, true)
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\WirelessNetView.exe /shtml ""c:\temp\wirelessnet.html"" /sort ~2""", 0, true)

return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\LAPTOP\Downloads\PortableApps\PortableApps\NIRLAUNCHER\NirSoft\LastActivityView /shtml ""c:\temp\lastactivity.html""", 0, true)

return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c c:\windows\rar a -r C:\temp\laptop.rar c:\temp\*.html", 0, true)

WScript.Sleep 5000

EmailSubject = "LAPTOP Online @ " & WAN_IP
EmailBody = "LAPTOP model:xxxx serial:xxxxx Part:xxxx Online @ " & WAN_IP


Const EmailFrom = "xxxx@xx.xx"
Const EmailFromName = "LAPTOP Security"
Const EmailTo = "xxxx@xx.xx"
'Const SMTPServer = "smtp.xx.com"
Const SMTPServer = "127.0.0.1"
'Const SMTPLogon = "xxxx@xx.xx"
'Const SMTPPassword = "xxxxx"
Const SMTPSSL = True
Const SMTPPort = 25
'Const SMTPPort = 465
'Const SMTPPort = 587

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1    'Send message using local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2  'Send the message using SMTP over TCP/IP networking.

Const cdoAnonymous = 0  ' No authentication
Const cdoBasic = 1  ' BASIC clear text authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2   ' NTLM, Microsoft proprietary authentication

Set recentFile = Nothing
Set recentFile1 = Nothing
Set recentFile2 = Nothing
Set recentFile3 = Nothing
Set recentFile4 = Nothing
Set recentFile5 = Nothing

For Each file in fso.GetFolder("C:\ProgramData\AutoScreenCap\ScreenshotCaptorPortable\Screenshots").Files
  If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
    Set recentFile = file
  ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
    set recentfile5 = recentfile4
    set recentfile4 = recentfile3
    set recentfile3 = recentfile2
    set recentfile2 = recentfile1
    set recentfile1 = recentfile
    Set recentFile = file
  End If
Next

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = EmailSubject
objMessage.From = """" & EmailFromName & """ <" & EmailFrom & ">"
objMessage.To = EmailTo
objMessage.TextBody = EmailBody
objMessage.AddAttachment recentFile
objMessage.AddAttachment recentFile5
objMessage.AddAttachment recentFile4
objMessage.AddAttachment recentFile3
objMessage.AddAttachment recentFile2
objMessage.AddAttachment recentFile1
objMessage.AddAttachment "c:\temp\ipconfig.txt"
objMessage.AddAttachment "c:\temp\laptop.rar"

' Second, configure the server

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTPPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
'Now send the message!
On Error Resume Next
objMessage.Send

fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\browserhistory.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\facebookcache.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\ipconfig.txt"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\whois.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\ReverseDNS.html"
WScript.Sleep 100
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\wifiinfo.html"
WScript.Sleep 100
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\wifihistory.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\laptop.rar"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\cprocess.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\turnon.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\wireless.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\wirelessnet.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\lastactivity.html"
fso.DeleteFile "c:\temp\wirelesskey.html"
```